# Is there a key for reporting or killing in Among Us?

Tags: among-us

In Among Us, You can use E instead of clicking to quick open tasks.

But is there a quick key to kill or report? I can't seem to figure one out.

Comment: Wait - *Among Us* is a multiplayer-only game, where chatting is a core part of gameplay, but it has no rebindable keys? That's scary.

Comment: @Dragomok How so? You can only chat during meetings, and during meetings you can only chat/vote, so what would you need to rebind keys for? WASD is standard for movement, E is near-universal "use" key, R for Report makes sense, and Q is just sort of right there so... Yeah, what would you even want to rebind them to?

Comment: maybe for people who don't use QWERTY? @NiettheDarkAbsol I'd like to rebind movement to `<AOE`, "use" to `>`, report to `P`, and kill to `;`. But, alas, I cannot.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol And I'm left handed so I use `IJKL`, because using `WSAD` comfortably would require me to push my keyboard all the way to the right, and then to push it back to chat. And that only works if the game doesn't use `Space`. And AutoHotKey doesn't mix with chat, because: randomDy repDacWng `WSAD` wWth `WASD` usuaDDy Deads to unreadabDe text. And Wf yQE add `QER` Wt gets even Rarder tQ read.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to [GameWith](https://gamewith.net/among-us-wiki/article/show/22175) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AmongUs/comments/iaaz0t/someone_asked_in_a_post_what_is_the_keyboard/), you can use the <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> buttons to kill and report respectively. A user in the Reddit thread mentioned if either aren't working, then you are probably focused on a particular task. If so, simply press
<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Tab also works for the map!